# How to find difference between two XML documents

Tags: iphone, xml

I want to compare two XML documents to find and show where is the difference
like diff utility in XCode.

I can retrieve and parse xml code using NSXMLParser in basic level,
and can tell 'they are not exactly same'

but I don't know how to tell 'where and which'.

Is there any open-source based library for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try following link
[XML Documents](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/06/14/openxmldiff-exe-a-utility-to-find-the-differences-between-two-open-xml-documents.aspx)

also [try this](http://www.factsandpeople.com/facts-mainmenu-5/20-xslt/59-difference-file-between-two-xml-files)

Comment: Thanks! Highly appreciated.I'm looking into it. 

For now, it seems that they require external utility (like xmldiff.exe). 

But I want to build an iphone app which retrieves XML documents from web (dynamically) and compare and show differences between them.

I wish there are pre-made objective-c version of opensource library. But if there are no such things, I will have to make it myself.. :(